# desktop.open in Java opens .bat file instead of a folder

Tags: java, windows

```
File file = new File ("D:\\Folder\\Folder2\\");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
    desktop.open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The following code supposed to open `Folder2`, but instead it opens `D:\Folder\Folder2.bat` file.
How to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried without the leading \ ?

Comment: Do you have a file called "D:\Folder\Folder2.bat"?  In Windows, you would see the same behavior from a command prompt if you just typed in "D:\Folder\Folder2".  You'll likely have to rename either the folder or the bat file.

Comment: @azro Same result

Comment: @ DM Graves It exists, and renaming it or the folder is not an option.

Comment: Then you're likely going to have to change your approach.  You'll probably need to launch explorer.exe with D:\Folder\Folder2 as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Opening folder through [`Deskopt.open()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) would be delegated to [`Desktop.browseFileDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browseFileDirectory-java.io.File-) (JDK 8/9)

But, as seen in [JDK-8233994](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8233994), that is not supported/implemented for Windows.

So the alternative with explorer.exe is indeed the recommended way:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select,D:\\Folder\\Folder2").start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Desktop** API describes the method open() clearly:

> Launches the associated application to open the file. If the specified
>   file is a directory, the file manager of the current platform is
>   launched to open it.

Or see the reply of @vonC